# Problem in installing pljava on windows

Tags: postgresql, pljava

Error on installing pl/java on windows 7 x64 and PostgreSQL 9.0.

```
CREATE FUNCTION sqlj.java_call_handler()
  RETURNS language_handler AS 'pljava'
  LANGUAGE C;
```

Error:

> ERROR:  could not load library
>   "C:/Program
>   Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib/pljava.dll":
>   The specified module could not be
>   found.
>
> *** *Error* *****
>
> ERROR: could not load library
>   "C:/Program
>   Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib/pljava.dll":
>   The specified module could not be
>   found. SQL state: 58P01

But I'm sure that pljava.dll exists in C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib

Comment: Most probably `pljava.dll` depends on some other DLL which is missing. Check with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it's possible to install PL/Java procedural language on PostgreSQL 9.0 64 bit on Windows 7 64 bit (I had same errore message as yours). I see (`C:/Program Files` path) that you have 64 bit version of PostgreSQL, so you need **64 bit** JRE (assuming `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6`):

- Download PL/Java 64 bit binary
  package from [pgFoundry](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pljava/) 
  (that is,
  `pljava-x86_64-w64-mingw32-pg9.0-1.4.2.tar.gz`)
- Unpack archive to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\share\pljava` directory
- Put `pljava.dll` into `C:\Program
  Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\lib` directory
- Add into `postgresql.conf` (data):

```
custom_variable_classes = 'pljava'
pljava.classpath='C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.0\\share\\pljava\\pljava.jar'
```

- Add into `PATH` (My Computer → Properties → Advanced → Environment Variables):

```
;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server
```

(you can create another `JRE_HOME` variable if you like and then write `;%JRE_HOME%\bin;%JRE_HOME%\bin\server`)

After that restart PostgreSQL service (postgresql-x64-9.0) and load `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\share\pljava\install.sql` again. Check:

```
postgres=# SELECT lanname FROM pg_language;
 lanname
----------
 internal
 c
 sql
 plpgsql
 java
 javau
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error and followed the instructions to a T, but still the same problem.  Turns out my PATH statement for the jre included quotes - assumed I needed them because of spaces in the directory names.  Removed the quotes from around the jre paths and the lights came on.

Hope this helps!